# C printf array and get open_stackdumpfile error

Tags: c, arrays, string, printf

on the command line the user would type:

> cmatch -i -n hello test1.in test2.in

"hello" is the string that the program will search for matching lines in the input files.

Now I'm stuck on printf this string.. I'm new to the C and don't know how the array of string works..

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){
       options opts;
       program_name = basename (argv[0]);
       scan_options (argc, argv, &opts);



       int arrLength=argc-optind;
       char *strings[arrLength];
       char *fileNames[arrLength-1];
       const int fileNamesLength=arrLength-1;

       int argi; int i=0;
       for (argi = optind; argi < argc; ++argi) {
          printf ("operand[%d] = \"%s\"\n", argi, argv[argi]); //printing operands
          strings[i]=argv[argi]; //assigning strings
          i++;
       }

       char *stringToMatch=strings[0];
       printf("String to match=%s\n",stringToMatch);

       int f;
   for(f=0; f<fileNamesLength; f++){
       fileNames[f]=strings[f+1];
       printf(fileNames[f]);
   }



       printf("GET THROUGH");
```

now the output is:

> operand[3] = "hello"
>
> operand[4] = "test1.in"
>
> operand[5] = "test2.in"
>
> String to match = "hello"
>
> ```
> 0 [main] cmatch 6092 open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to cmatch.exe.stackdump
> ```

so what's wrong with the *stringToMatch?

Comment: what is `optind` set to? I don't see it defined anywhere

Comment: It is the position of the first operand after the last -option. It's provided by my teacher..

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: I'm not sure.... I write the code in Eclipse and compile the file using gcc Run->cmd

Comment: so then your compiler is GCC. I am using Visual Studio 2013 and tested your code. I had to assign a constant value of `3` to `optind` and modify the code slightly to account for missing functions and different semantics, but when I ran it, I could not reproduce your error. Is there any more information you can provide? Like the actual stack trace, call stack or more detailed error information?

Comment: I'm new to C so I have no idea how to provide extra information you asked.. Now printf doesn't even work as the first statement in the main function..

Comment: Are you including ALL of the output or are you leaving some info out?

Answer (score 0):

To print a "string" in C (array of char) you can do the following:

```
printf("%s\n", filenames[f]);
```

Also to compare two strings in c you would need to do the following:

```
#include <string.h>
```

and then use the function strcmp as follows to check if two strings are equal:

```
if(strcmp(name1, name2)==0)
```

Also, i would recommend avoiding lines like this:

```
fileNames[f]=strings[f+1];
```

you might access memory outside of your scope. Instead assign the string you're searching to a variable and use that. So the comparison part would look something like this:

```
if(strcmp(constname, strings[f])==0)
```

I hope this helps!